# What's going wrong with this SOCKS proxy request?

Tags: c++, winsock, socks

I'm currently trying to implement SOCKS 4/5 functionality in my C++ program (i.e. requests to arbitrary protocols and hosts can be redirected through a given SOCKS proxy if desired). I'm developing purely for Windows so using Winsock 2.

My problem is slightly less abstract than simply "how does this work" though. I've read the RFC for SOCKS 4 (I decided to implement SOCKS 4 first since it has less bytes in its requests to contend with) but I'm struggling to create the C string I need to **send()**.

At present, I have a struct defined called *Socks4Msg* which looks like this:

```
struct Socks4Msg {
const static uint8_t version = 0x04; //SOCKS version 4 (obviously)
const static uint8_t command = 0x01; //1 is TCP CONNECT command
const static uint8_t nullbyte = 0x00; //null byte sent at message end

uint16_t port; //16 bit/2 byte port (network order)
uint32_t ip; //32 bit/4 byte IP address (network order)
Socks4Msg(uint16_t p, uint32_t i) : port(p), ip(i) { }
};
```

The function which creates the actual socket and does the work is here (where p and h hold the port and host to test *through* the proxy -- p is a string to maintain compatibility with HttpProxy which I've already implemented). port and addr are part of the class and are an int and string respectively; they're the details of the proxy server.

```
int Socks4Proxy::test(std::string p, std::string h) const {
uint16_t network_port = htons(str_to_numt<uint16_t>(p));
uint32_t network_ip = hostname_to_ip(h);
Socks4Msg msg_struct(network_port,network_ip);

SOCKET s = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
int last_error;
if(s == INVALID_SOCKET) {
              last_error = WSAGetLastError();
              std::cerr << "Failed to initialise socket! Error code: " << last_error << std::endl; 
              return 2;
}

sockaddr_in st_addr;
st_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
st_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
ipaddr_t ip = inet_addr(addr.c_str());
st_addr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = ip;

if(connect(s,(sockaddr*)&st_addr,sizeof(st_addr))!=0) {
                                                      last_error = WSAGetLastError();
                                                      std::cerr << "Socket failed to connect. Error code: " << last_error << std::endl;
                                                      return 2;  
}

uint8_t message[13];
uint8_t* message_ptr;
memset(message, 0, 13);
message_ptr = message;
*message_ptr = msg_struct.version;
message_ptr++;
*message_ptr = msg_struct.command;
message_ptr++;
*message_ptr = msg_struct.port;
message_ptr += 2;
*message_ptr = msg_struct.ip;
message_ptr += 4;
*message_ptr = 'b'; message_ptr++; *message_ptr = 'o'; message_ptr++; *message_ptr = 'b'; message_ptr++;
*message_ptr = msg_struct.nullbyte;
message_ptr++;
*message_ptr = 0x00;
char smessage[13];
memcpy(smessage, message, 13);

int return_val;
while(return_val = send(s, smessage, strlen(smessage), 0)) {
                       if(return_val == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                                     last_error = WSAGetLastError();
                                     std::cerr << "Writing data failed. Error code: " << last_error << std::endl;
                                     return 2;
                       }
                       //implement return_val < strlen(message) here
                       else break;
}
//remainder of function
```

I have tested and verified that the members of msg_struct contain the correct data (and in the correct byte order) before the C string manipulation starts.

I've tried doing it using **memcpy()** (e.g. memcpy(message_ptr, &msg_struct.port, 2)) in place of the assignments but I just can't understand why Wireshack always quotes the byte length of the sent data as 2 (i.e. version and command) but nothing else. (I know my knowledge of C strings - and therefore the code at that point - is a bit rough but I can't explain why it doesn't work)

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `message_ptr` is `uint8_t*` and `*message_ptr = msg_struct.ip;` is wrong. You should cast `message_ptr` to `uint_32t*` and then assign data, like `* ((uint32_t*)message_ptr) = msg_struct.ip;` otherwise msg_struct.ip will be converted to uint8_t and then assigned. Same problems with other fields.

Check this and let me know if it is woring again :)

BTW. I think Wireshark network traffic analyzer could help you a lot in searching such kind of problems.

**UPDATE**

Probably a better idea is to create a structure which represents the message you want to send and cast `message_ptr` to the pointer on this structure. But do not forget to tell your compiler not to add any paddings.

**UPDATE 2**

Network and host byte order.

Do not forget that you should change bytes order using hton, ntoh, htonl or ntohl functions.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. 
Okay, I added the casts 
    \*((uint16_t*)message_ptr) and 
    \*((uint32_t*)message_ptr) for port and IP respectively. No change though. Wireshark reports the message body is 0x04 0x01 which is perfectly fine in that it's right, it's just truncated badly. Awfully even. :P

Comment: check strlen(smessage) value. It could be very small, because you could have '\0's in your text and protocol messages are not text ;) As far as I can see it will be at least 1 byte less than you expecting because of `*message_ptr = msg_struct.nullbyte;`

Comment: On the idea of putting the whole thing in a struct: that's not a bad idea at all. Probably should've thought of it a few hours ago and saved some of my hair but at least there's still some left. :)

Cheers, I'll do that and see what happens.

Comment: I see you are new here. Just a small advice - do not forget to click + and accept solutions to give thanks to other ppl for help. Good luck ;)

Comment: Result! strlen() returns 2. And *that* would be my problem! Sat there staring at every line for a while and it never occurred to me. Thanks, will do.

Comment: You are welcome. It happens to everybody, when you are trying to figure out what is wrong for few hours and then another guy find the problem in few sec :D